# merge two arrays from a plist file into one

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, plist

Basically i have created an app that selects random strings from a given plist and then displays them to the user. Currently i have one directory for say truth and one for dare and the user clicks on truth shows truth and dare when they click on that it shows dare.

Keeping the same structure i would like to add a random button to allow the user to click on random and it displays either a truth or a dare how would i go about reading data from both arrays.

I would like to combine the two arrays into one and then output a random question. I have tried to google it but seem to be getting stuck on this one.

This is my code

```
- (IBAction)dare:(id)sender {
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"extreme" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"dare"];

int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count;

self.joke.text = plistArray[randV];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);
```

}

Plist structure 
[image: Plist structure]

```
- (IBAction)truth:(id)sender {


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"extremem" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"truth"];

int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count;


self.joke.text = plistArray[randV];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);
```

}

Also how would i ensure that the user is not asked the same question twice? I was thinking along the lines of a variable to set yes or no and if they are yes then ask then no dont ask? how would we do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this code. Only problem is i cant seem to release the arrays?

what you guys think?

```
- (IBAction)truth:(id)sender {


NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
                  @"test" ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *plistDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray = plistDict[@"truth"];
NSDictionary *plistDict2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSMutableArray *plistArray2 = plistDict2[@"dare"];

plistArray = [plistArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:plistArray2];

NSLog(@"%@", plistArray);


int randV = arc4random() % plistArray.count;


self.joke.text = plistArray[randV];

NSLog(@"dictionary: %@, array: %@", plistDict, plistArray);
```

}

Comment: Why do u want to release the arrays? These are local variables which get dealloced as soon as function exit.

Comment: Ohh yea sorry as im a beginer this is still all new